# Android app not receiving gcm notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add notifications to my Android app using GCM. I started out by following this 
[tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-get-started-with-push-notifications-on-android--cms-25870) and using [this example project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart) as a reference.

I followed all the steps and created all needed classes and services, but I am still not receiving any notifications. 
I'm checking for Google Play Services and seem to register my device successfully on my server. I added the google-services.json file to my project and added all permissions and libraries to the project.

**What is going wrong?**
Did I forget anything? Do I still need to do something? I'm very confused at this point.

**AndroidManifest**

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<permission android:name="com.manager_android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.manager_android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Receiver and services

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.manager_android" />
            <!--here-->
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".Activities.GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".Activities.TokenRefreshListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".Activities.RegistrationService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

Added to app **build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Added to project **build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

**RegistrationService**

```
public class RegistrationService extends IntentService {

public RegistrationService() {
    super("");
}

private final String TAG = "RegistrationInfo";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    registerDevice();
}

private void registerDevice() {
    InstanceID myID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    String registratonToken = "";
    try {
        registratonToken = myID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        log.d("Registration Token", registratonToken);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_id", registratonToken);
        params.put("platform", "GCM");
        SaveSharedPreference.setToken(getApplicationContext(), registratonToken);

        //Register token on server
        Communication.post(getString(R.string.register_device_url), new RequestParams(params), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Registration was successful");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Registration failed.");
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't register device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**TokenRefreshListenerService**

```
public class TokenRefreshListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationService.class);
    startService(i);
}
}
```

**GCMIntentService**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends GcmListenerService {

private int testId = 1234;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    sendNotification(message);
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreenActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), testId, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(testId, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

I start the RegistrationService as a service when the user logs in to register the device.

Comment: Test here online with your registration token is your code work fine or not http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with the website and I did receive the notifications, so now i believe the problem is not in my app but in sending the notification from the server.

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) can help you understand about notifications.

> A notification is a message you display to the user outside of your
>   app's normal UI. When you tell the system to issue a notification, it
>   first appears as an icon in the notification area. To see the details
>   of the notification, the user opens the notification drawer. Both the
>   notification area and the notification drawer are system-controlled
>   areas that the user can view at any time.

It also provides sample codes on every topic that you will tackle.

For GCM, you can refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm).

> Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that enables developers
>   to send messages between servers and client apps. This includes
>   downstream messages from servers to client apps, and upstream messages
>   from client apps to servers.

It will help you understand about the concept of GCM. Also it provides [sample](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/samples) to start with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Today I found out that the problem wasn't in my app but on the server side... The notifications weren't sent correctly which is why I didn't receive any notifications. Thanks anyway